# Firebase PushViewController to push multiple times

Tags: swift, firebase

In my project I deleted all the segues in the storyboard and changed all the

```
performSegue...
```

to be a

```
pushViewController...
```

In my app 75% of the time this works perfectly. However when I am inside of a Firebase method and I try to do so the VC I am pushing flashes on the screen several times.

Firebase has something to do with it I think because I created a simple method

```
func testDel() {
    if let addVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCardVC") as? AddCardViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addVC, animated: true)
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

It worked EXACTLY as it was supposed to, went to the 2nd VC and that was it...

Before I post my code, I apologize for deleting my original question. I had too many edits.

So far I have tried wrapping the push inside a

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {...}
```

This had no effect.

I went to the 2nd VC and commented out all the functions and put breakpoints on ANY line that had a pushVC on it just to see if it was triggering automatically...

I have put a print statement in the method right after the push and it prints once. I also put a print statement in the 2nd VC ViewWillAppear and that gets called 5 times.

I tried commenting out my push code and re adding a segue line on the storyboard and segueing the old fashioned way and it did a similar thing, however I got a log in the console saying

> unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   uiviewcontroller...

This does not appear when I use push

I also found an older post on SO where somebody suggested the following code

```
var shouldPush = true

if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
if viewController is AddCardViewController {
shouldPush = false
}
}
}

if shouldPush {
let addCrd = AddCardViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)                       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addCrd, animated: true)
}
```

This made the flashing go from around 5 to 2. Still not great.

My full code is this

```
// MARK: Delete Card with UIAlert

func deleteCard() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Wait!", message: "This will completely remove this card from your account. All the services linked to this card will be removed. Your total fixed monthly expenses will also be erased!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Never Mind!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "I Understand!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result: UIAlertAction) in

        let thisCard = self.ref.child("cards").child(self.thisCardIDTransfered)
        let thisCardInUsers = self.ref.child("users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("cards").child(self.thisCardIDTransfered)

        thisCard.removeValue()
        thisCardInUsers.removeValue()

        let cardNode = self.ref.child("users").child((self.user?.uid)!).child("cards")

        cardNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren() {

                if let walletVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalletVC") as? CardWalletViewController {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(walletVC, animated: true)
                }

            } else {

                if let addVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCardVC") as? AddCardViewController {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addVC, animated: true)
                    print("foo")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your alertController will most likely be displayed before the items have been deleted from firebase, which also means the walletVC and addVC will display after the alert controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So somebody helped me, it was very confusing as why the order of print statements were occurring until he saw the rest of my project...

On other ViewControllers I had Firebase observe methods....when I would push to another VC I was just adding to a stack...that method was still running in the background so I had 2+ observers doing a pushViewController ..

We ended up changing some of them to be ObserveSingleEvent...
He told me alternatively we could have done the

```
viewDidDisappear
```

So i guess it helped me understand better how apps work.

Answer (score 0):

```
cardNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren() {
               ...

            } else {

            ...
        })
```

This observer may be called multiple times and making your view getting pushed multiple times,maybe checking what the snapshot contains can help you solve the problem. I'm guessing sometimes this observer fires off and the snapshot is probably Null.

```
cardNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            //do Nothing
        } else {
           //check if it contains children
        }
```

I wouldn't recommend using observers to dictate what view you should show. Especially since you are listening to `.value`, because they might fire off unexpectedly and forgetting to remove the observers can lead to many bugs.

Comment: Why would the observer get called multiple times? Also the observer is not dictating which viewcontroller is displayed - it's a one shot loading data from a node so what's dictating which view controller is displayed is based on if the snapshot has any child nodes. If there are children the user can interact via the walletVC and there are no children the user can add via the addCardVC